# Trying to show the data appearing in main screen on pop up also

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to show the data appearing in main screen on pop up, but not getting any  idea how to do that.The data bind on main screen is binding through database
this is the data appearing on main screen
c# code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped rht-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><h2><strong>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "TicketDetails", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</strong></h2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bg-danger" style="background: #2d323e !important; border-radius: 10px;">

                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "CreatedBy", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "CreationDate", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "IssueType", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "AssignedTo", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "ClosedBy", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "ClosedDate", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>

                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Description", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th>@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Status", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</th>
                    <th style="padding:0px 10px;">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "TimeRemaining", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <p style="font-size:11px; margin-bottom: 5px;">HH:MM:SS</p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.CreatedName)</td>
                        <td>@item.CreatedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</td>
                        @*<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.IssueType)</td>*@
                        <td class="Esctyp"><a id="Esc_@item.EscId" class="crsr-pnt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EscModal">@item.IssueType</a></td>                        
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.AssignedPerson)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ClosedBy)</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (item.ClosedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy") != "01 January 0001")
                            {
                                @Html.Raw(item.ClosedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"))
                            }
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @if (item.CreatorDescription.Length > 10)
                            {
                                @Html.Raw(item.CreatorDescription.Substring(0, 10) + "...")
                            }
                            else
                            {@Html.Raw(item.CreatorDescription) }
                        </td>
                        @*<td id="statusdiv_@item.EscId" class="statusdiv">@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status).ToString(), "Escalation")</td>*@                        
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status)</td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="clockdiv_@item.EscId" class="clockdiv" tat="@item.CreatedDate.AddHours(item.TAT)">
                                <div style="display:inline-flex;">
                                    <span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is the way the popup data design is looking and my requirement is to fill the data in this popup design template with same value which is appearing on main screen
c# code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EscModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@Session["Name"].ToString() (@Session["ErpCode"].ToString()) - @Html.TextBox("AtDate")</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "zone", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                       @Html.TextBox("zone")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Department", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.TextBox("Department")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "CreatedBy", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.TextBox("CreatedBy")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "CreationDate", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.TextBox("Date")                       
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Priority", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlPriority", new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "High" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Medium", Value = "Medium" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Low", Value = "Low" },
                     }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "IssueType", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.TextBox("IssueType")
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "AssignedTo", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.TextBox("AssignedTo")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Forward", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlEmployee", new SelectList(ViewBag.Employee, "ErpCode", "Name", ViewData["Empl"]), "-- " +
             HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Forward", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString() + " --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>                    
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Status", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.DropDownList("ddlPriority", new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Text = "Open", Value = "Open" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Close", Value = "Close" },
                     }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Remarks", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo)
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        @Html.TextArea("txtDescription", "", new { @class = "form-control", rows = "3", placeholder = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Description", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo) })
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-12">                   
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Attachment", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                       @Html.TextBox("Attachment","", new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnCncl" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Close", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(_vpth, "Save", _owrpr.GlobalCultureInfo).ToString()</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to bind the data in popup through jquery like this but is anybody can suggest how to do that
Jquery

```
$(".Esctyp").click(function () {
 $('#zone').val(_lval[0]).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#Branch').val(_lval[1]).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#CreatedBy').val(_lval[2]).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#Date').val(_lval[3]).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#ClosedBy').val(_lval[4]).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#ClosedDate').val(_lval[5]).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#ddlPriority').val(_lval[6]).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#IssueType').val(_lval[7]).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('#AssignedTo').val(_lval[8]);
        $('#txtDescription').val(_lval[9]);
        $('#ddlPriority').val(_lval[10]);
        $('#IssueDescription').val(_lval[11]);
        $('#ddlEmployee').val(_lval[12]);
        $('#Attachment').val(_lval[13]);
    });
```

All the visual description are in given image[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the values from each table cell in the row you clicked on? - if so `$('.Esctyp').click(function() { var row = $(this).closest('tr').find('td'); var createdName = row.eq(0).text(); });` will return the value of the first `<td>` element

Comment: @StephenMueckeyes i want if user click on first row cell, data on popup will appear of same first row cell .here i tried the code which you have given  but not getting values.

Comment: Of course it does :) The value of `createdName` will contain the text that is in the first cell of the row you clicked.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i'm new to jquery .i am trying as you said but the value is not appearing.could you  suggest  how to do or any example

Comment: I have not told you how to show it - just to get it. Just use `$(someElement).val(createdName);` - I'm assuming the element is `'#CreatedBy'` but your code is such a mess its hard to tell. And in future, don't just dump all your code here - 90% of it is irrelevant to your question

Comment: @StephenMueckeThx i will take care of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135353/discussion-between-anuj-and-stephen-muecke).